# Extract few fields from JSON and return rest as a map in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am reading a streaming data in pyspark dataframe, the data contains few fields which are present in every data/request. I want to exact those fields and create a dataframe column for it and want to store the rest of fields as map in another dataframe column. I am not able to achieve it

If someone can help with it?

Example:

Sample Values :

```
{"event1":"Value","event2":"Value","event3":"Value","event4":"Value","event5":"Value","event6":"Value"}
{"event1":"Value","event2":"Value","event3":"Value","data1":"Value","data2":"Value","data3":"Value"}
```

Now suppose event1,event2,event3 is present in every row, so I want to extract it and make it as a  separate dataframe column and rest of the fields as map of key values pairs which will be another dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a schema for your dataframe  and use `from_json` to convert it to `StructType` in spark.
Then you are able to select your specific event's and create another dataframe for other events.

Comment: But I want to write that data to parquet, creating 2 dataframes will result into creation of different parquet files.

Comment: It’s still okay. You need a schema for that